# list all downstream local branches in git

Tags: git

As a development workflow I create a lot of local branches and use the `git branch -u` feature to keep track of dependencies between my local branches. Doing this makes it easy to check whether a single patch/feature is out of sync with the patch/feature it depends on and to rebase when that happens.

It's possible to show the upstream branch of the current branch using the following command:

```
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref '@{upstream}'
```

And for an arbitrary branch `foo` using the following command will show the name of the branch being tracked.

```
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref 'foo@{upstream}'
```

By design, a branch can only have one upstream branch that it's tracking. Naturally, there's no such restriction in the other direction.

*Is there a way of listing which local branches are tracking a particular branch without walking every branch?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way of listing which local branches are tracking a particular branch without walking every branch?

No.  However, there are easy ways to walk all local branches:

- `git branch` does it for you: `git branch -vv` prints the name of each branch and additional information about it, including its upstream if set.
- `git for-each-ref` allows you to construct your own walk of *any part* of the reference space.  The branch names are under the `refs/heads/` part of this space, so:

  ```
  git for-each-ref refs/heads
  ```

  prints all of your branches.  The default format does not include their upstream settings, but see [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref) for how to control the formats.

Note that `git branch` can be told to look at the `refs/remotes/` remote-tracking names, using `-r`, instead of the local branches.  You can direct it to show both spaces (`refs/heads/*` and `refs/remotes/*`) using `-a`.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that the git configuration lists branch mappings. Note that I have not read the details on this and it may not work in certain situations, so I am just giving it as a possible way forward.

```sh
git config --local --list | grep 'refs/heads/<remote-branch>'
```

whis produces the following output:

```
branch.<local-branch1>.merge=refs/heads/<remote-branch>
branch.<local-branch2>.merge=refs/heads/<remote-branch>
```

You may need to tweak your `grep` as it may be possible for remote branch references to be listed in other contexts as well. But this should get you started.